# Invoke a shell script on particular time which is read from a file

Tags: unix, awk, sh, ksh

My requirement is to run a unix script based on time which is read from a csv file.

The Csv file will have the contents along with time in 24Hours clock , the script should read the time from that and invoke the script which will perform a task. This should be continuous

If there are 100 rows the Time should be read and the script should run , Also other coulmn details corresponding to that time match should go as parameter.

Example csv:

```
Worflow 1,Folder 1,Dev,10:30
Worflow 2,Folder 2,Dev,11:30
Worflow 3,Folder 3,Dev,12:30
Worflow 4,Folder 4,Dev,13:30
```

The script will read column 4 and check the current time if it matches it should pass the 1,2,3 coulmn value as parameter to the invoking script . It should run continuously.

Any Help would be Appriciated

ksh, sh on AIX machine

Comment: Why are you not using the built-in scheduling of the OS?

Comment: Hey sorry i'm a newbie to unix and not much aware of this , im using putty to connect to unix from a windows machine . will that be possible there

Comment: The functionality you describe is provided by the UNIX tool `cron`. Just google it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to the comment, I'm not sure that you need to continuously monitor the file. If not, you might try executing the script with [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/). That will allow you to specify specific days, times, intervals, etc. on which the script will be run. To edit your crontab, try typing `crontab -e` from the command line and see if it dumps you into an editor of some sort. If need be, you could even write a script that executes once per minute and parses the file that has the run times in it and executes your other script when the times conditional is met.

Comment: Thanks for your Response that was helpful , any inputs for checking the csv file and reading the Time

Comment: I would probably write an awk script that translates the csv file into a file like that used for crontab and then import it with `crontab importjobs.txt` as suggested [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/how-to-install-edit-or-remove-cron-jobs-in-batch-mode/). Just remember that if you're using crontab to run your translator/importer every minute that you'll want to include that job in the imported list so that cron keeps running it.